# Current shoutcast track poster in jplayer

Tags: streaming, jplayer, shoutcast

I have integrated jplayer with shoutcast and its working properly.
Is it possible to show played list like kast player with jplayer as well for shoutcast ? I tried to list them as playlist but its not working .

Comment: You will have to create a separate script for that, jPlayer does not support that out of the box.

Comment: jPlayer provides a playlist add on http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

You should just be able to serve it an array of your media. This shows the current track poster too.